# Print output before writing to file haskell

Tags: haskell, printing

Suppose I have this code:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
            ... --some code that gets an array of ByteStrings called "files"
            putStrLn "Saving myFile1"
            B.writeFile "myFile1.bin" $ files!!0
            putStrLn "Saving myFile2"
            B.writeFile "myFile2.bin" $ files!!1
            putStrLn "Done!"
```

Instead of printing out each string before the subsequent file writing, it just seems to print out everything at once after the files have been saved. This kind of functionality is inconvenient for notifying the user of the progress, since they'll only get these messages once all the file writing is done.

My code is obviously not this bad (I'm using a list of functions with `sequence`) but this illustrates the problem well. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is this there no way around this?

Comment: Looks to me like a *buffering* problem.

Comment: We might need to see more code since is clear that this example doesn't produce the phenomenon. You mention `sequence` ; this might be the source of the problem.

Comment: In particular, how are you getting the list of bytestrings that you are successively writing?

Comment: Have you tried to change your buffering mode? Add `hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering` to the IO before the operations and import `System.IO` .

Comment: Note that these types of informational message are usually better written to standard error rather than standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Like @WillemVanOnsem stated, this is a buffering issue. You can manually flush the buffer after each print or you can [change the buffering mode entirely](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:12).

```
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
            ... --some code that gets an array of ByteStrings called "files"
            putStrLn "Saving myFile1"
            hFlush stdout
            B.writeFile "myFile1.bin" $ files!!0
            putStrLn "Saving myFile2"
            hFlush stdout
            B.writeFile "myFile2.bin" $ files!!1
            putStrLn "Done!"
            hFlush stdout
```

or

```
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
            ... --some code that gets an array of ByteStrings called "files"
            hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
            putStrLn "Saving myFile1"
            B.writeFile "myFile1.bin" $ files!!0
            putStrLn "Saving myFile2"
            B.writeFile "myFile2.bin" $ files!!1
            putStrLn "Done!"
```